# Is there a reason why array cannot be referenced in a keep= data set options?

Tags: sas

The following is the code.

```
data WORK.TOTALSALES(keep=MonthSales{12}); 
     set WORK.MONTHLYSALES(keep=Year Product Sales); 
     array MonthSales{12}; 
     do i=1 to 12; 
        MonthSales{i}=Sales;
     end;
     drop i;
run;
```

Many thanks for your time and attention.

Answer (score 3):

The `keep=` dataset option does not support arrays, but it does support sequentially numbered variables.

```
data WORK.TOTALSALES(keep=MonthSales1-MonthSales12); 
     set WORK.MONTHLYSALES(keep=Year Product Sales); 
     array MonthSales{12}; 
     do i=1 to 12; 
        MonthSales{i}=Sales;
     end;
     drop i;
run;
```

Comment: Or, alternatively, variables with the same prefix, e.g. `keep=sales:` would keep sales2012a, sales2012b, sales2013a, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A SAS array, as documented in [SAS(R) 9.4 Language Reference: Concepts, Fifth Edition](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/68089/HTML/default/p1kf03v09wlxk5n1qw71qhgzgbg7.htm#n0uxm2nrwthmv5n1pfm4pwdah04y) has the following restriction:

> An array definition is in effect only for the duration of the DATA
>   step. If you want to use the same array in several DATA steps, you
>   must redefine the array in each step.

So even if you were to use the `drop=` (instead of `keep=`) data set option on `WORK.TOTALSALES` for some other variables in the data step, the array would still not be part of the output data set as it only exists within the data step that it is defined in with the `array` statement.

Answer (score 0):

A SAS Array in a Data Step is just a logical grouping of variables.  That grouping is only available to the processing inside that data step.  Data set options like `drop=` and `keep=` are handled by the SAS IO system, which is independent of the Data Step.